# How to get horizontal scrolling active in a Kivy Recycleview?

Tags: python, kivy, scrollbar

I need to be able to scroll horizontally in a RecycleView that i'm using in my app, but can't get it to work. I found a working script for ScrollView, but that doesn't seem to work with a RecycleView.

I made a small working example, where *do_scroll_x* should allow me to scroll horizontally, but i don't get a scrollbar and dragging won't help either. Is anyone able to show me an example that actually works?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView

Builder.load_string('''
<table@BoxLayout>:
    col1: ''
    col2: ''
    col3: ''
    col4: ''
    size_hint: None, None
    width: 1600
    height: 32
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label:
        text: root.col1
    Label:
        text: root.col2
    Label:
        text: root.col3
    Label:
        text: root.col4

<RV>:
    viewclass: 'table'
    scroll_type: ['bars','content']
    bar_width: 16
    do_scroll_x: True
    do_scroll_y: True
    size_hint: 1, 1
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, None
        default_size_hint: None, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
''')

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'col1': 'Just some Text to fill the void', 'col2': 'Another, shorter Text', 'col3': f'And now some numbers: {x}', 'col4': 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor'} for x in range(200)]


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `kv`, you just need to do the same for the horizontal direction as you have done for vertical. Modify your `RecycleBoxLayout` rule to include:

```
    size_hint_y: None
    size_hint_x: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    width: self.minimum_width
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver, thanks! It's annoying that the solution is so simple and yet i couldn't find it on my own.